# The probability of choosing two elements from 20 elements

Tags: probability

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> We have 20 elements and two of those elements are randomly chosen.
>   What is the probability of choosing the two randomly selected
>   elements? And what is the probability of choosing one?

My answers are:

The probability of choosing two are: $1/\binom{20}{2}$

The probability of choosing one are: $1/\binom{20}{1}$

Are my answers correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your first one is correct. There are a total of ${20\choose2}$ possible ways to choose the two elements. And there is only one way to randomly select them.
$$\text{Probability}=\frac1{20\choose2}=\frac1{190}$$

For the second part, There are still the same numbers of possibilities, so the denominator will be the same. How can we sandimly select only one of the chosen elements? First, we choose which one we selected $2\choose1$, then we choose the other element we select from the $18$ that weren't chosen $18\choose1$. This gives us
$$\text{Probability}=\frac{{2\choose1}{18\choose1}}{20\choose2}=\frac{36}{190}$$